# Nth power of number in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

How to find nth power of a number in crystal reports.

```
For E.g

For 2 to the power of 4 should return 16
2 to the power of 5 should return 32.
```

Comment: Have you tried using the POWER Function?

Comment: Actually I couldn't any function like "POWER"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The caret (`^`) is the operator you're looking for.

Example: `2 ^ 4` evaluates to 16 and `2 ^ 5` evaluates to 32

Answer (score 0):

Somehow managed to solve my problem, though the solution is weird. Posting it so that any one can use.

Local stringVar array x := ['c1','c2'];

```
Local NumberVar i;
Local NumberVar j:=1;

For i:=0 to (Count(x)) do
(
if(i=0) then
(
j:=2;
)
else
j:=(j*2)+(j*2);

i:=i+1;
);

Count(x);
if(Count(x)=1) then
(
j:=2;
)
else
j/2;
```